# Import android support not being resolved

Tags: android, android-appcompat, revision

I am working on an android project where Android support library v7-appcompat is being added by eclipse.Now after following android developers website, I have added dependency for this support library.My project is free of errors but while running the project i am getting the error **"The Import android.support.v7 cannot be resolved"**.I am attaching the log file and my main activity.I have followed almost every post related to this topic on SO but  the issue is not resolved yet.

> LOGCAT

```
05-26 12:07:19.613: E/AndroidRuntime(18953): java.lang.Error: Unresolved compilation problem: 
05-26 12:07:19.613: E/AndroidRuntime(18953):    The import android.support.v7 cannot be resolved
05-26 12:07:19.613: E/AndroidRuntime(18953):    at com.sim.clientkeeper.MainActivity.<init>(MainActivity.java:7)
05-26 12:07:19.613: E/AndroidRuntime(18953):    at java.lang.Class.newInstanceImpl(Native Method)



`import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBar;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;

import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    SQLiteDatabase sqlDba;
    SQLiteAdapter DbAdapter;
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        DbAdapter = new SQLiteAdapter(getApplicationContext());
          DbAdapter.open();

    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
        int id = item.getItemId();
        if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
            return true;
        }
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }

    public void onClickClient(View v)
    {
        Intent i=new Intent(this,CLient_List_Activity.class);
        startActivity(i);
    }

    public void onClickTravel(View v)
    {
        Intent i=new Intent(this,Travel_Activity.class);
        startActivity(i);
    }

    }
`
```

I have added the appcompat library from project-->properties-->android-->adding it in the library section.
I am extending my MainActivity from AppCompatActivity as mentioned in earlier posts about the same topic.

Comment: you are using Android studio or eclipse ?

Comment: I am using  Eclipse.

Comment: import android.app.Activity; what is " ` " in the import line ?

Comment: " ' " is not part of my code. This came while posting the question.

Comment: Hi, I removed import android.support.v7.app.ActionBar, but getting same error.

Comment: how to do it in android studio ?

Answer (score 1):

Just delete `android-support-v4.jar` from libs folder of your project. Rest of the things/errors will be gone. Eclipse will handle rest of the things.

if error still exist then try to remove unused imports & clean your project or  restart your eclipse.

Comment: I don't have any jar file in my project's libs folder.

Answer (score 0):

I think you have not added the App compact-v7 into uild path and also , please right click on your project and then navigate to the Properties , now in new dialog box click to android , select the appropriate android version and in down below in Library section add appcompact-v7 library . Hit apply and ok. 
Clean your project. That is what worked for me

Comment: I did everything from going to properties and adding appcompat v7 as a library to my project. It is not working.

Comment: some times it happens , please check again that if it is still there in that section and not turned red from green ?

Comment: I removed and added again as you said and still of no help.:(

Comment: No I was saying that , tell me if it is red or not, Once after you have added in the way I described. please check and tell me

Comment: android-support-v7-appcompat has a green check mark.

Comment: so tel me how you have imported  android.support.v7 this into eclipse ?